# Generate Astro index page as well as pagination

Tags: astrojs

I have a static site with a blog section using Astro's built-in pagination, doing something like this in `src/pages/blog/[page].astro`:

```
export const itemsPerPage = 12

export async function getStaticPaths({ paginate }) {
  const allBlogs = await Astro.glob('./*.md')
  return paginate(allBlogs, { pageSize: itemsPerPage })
}

const { page } = Astro.props
const { start, end, total, data, currentPage } = page
```

The `page` props are then used to populate the pagination UI. This all works fine, and results in `/blog/1`, `/blog/2` etc pages being built.

What I would like to do is have `src/pages/blog/index.astro` to generate `/blog`, which would have the same content as the first page e.g. `/blog/1`. I can replicate the logic to get the posts, but I can't figure out how to access the pagination data outside of `getStaticPaths`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dynamic routes](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/routing/#dynamic-routes) in Astro like `src/pages/blog/[page].astro` only work one level deep to create pages like `/blog/[page]`, but the route you want (`/blog`) is deeper than your dynamic route can create so you have to switch to a [REST parameter](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/routing/#example-dynamic-pages-at-multiple-levels) in your dynamic route like `src/pages/blog/[...page].astro` which will allow you to [create urls at any depth](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/routing/#example-dynamic-pages-at-multiple-levels) `/blog`, `/blog/2`, `/blog/2022/1`, etc

Comment: Amazing, all I had to do was change from `[page].astro` to `[...page].astro` and it works as I expect, although I will need to re-read that documentation page a few more times to understand exactly how...